# Best places to study Algebra II and Precalculus?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, geometry

I really like Khan Acadey and Alcumus(I have the books as well) but Khan Academy in lagging all the time and Alcumus, well, is not so well organised like KA. Are there any other websites like this or a way to fix KA? Quickly, before this is closed for one reason or another. XD

Comment: Well, they don't lag much, the exercises are lagging. Sometimes, I can't go to the next problem, I have to reload and I lose all that I've solved 5mins earlier...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you believe in learning by practice then [brilliant.org](http://brilliant.org) is golden. It may seem a little hard at first but if you persevere a little then the rewards are amazing. There is also a points system; if you get a certain number of points then you can earn a prize!

Have fun!

Comment: Nice one, I love it.

Comment: @Antoni4040 Also, if you upgrade to Brilliant$^2$ then you also have access to Calculus, Probability among other things.

Answer (score 1):

Try coursera.org. If you haven't heard of it, it runs online courses from a bunch of different colleges on different subjects (typical course format: video lectures, homework assignments, sometimes a few quizzes and usually a final test). There's a precalculus course starting on the 23rd (of June) from UC Irvine. Not sure about Algebra II.

Answer (score 1):

**PatrickJMT** (on Youtube) is marvellous. He explains everything intuitively and gives lots of examples (which you can do by pausing the video).

Plus, he's on Youtube, which is as fast as any video-streaming service is going to get.

https://www.youtube.com/user/patrickJMT

Comment: Thanks, that looks nice, but what I really like in KA is the system of exercises(levels, badges, etc.). Any platform like that?